# How to use Editfor in jquery datatable using ASP.net MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, datatable

I am using Jquery Datatable in asp.net MVC. I bind the sql query in datatable and the datatable i am using one Editfor, here i am using datetime picker. i attached my code on below. please help me.

```
<table id="datatable" class="display" border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RMAKey)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SalesPerson)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SalesRep)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Datecreated)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.First().FollowupDate)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.First().FollowupDate)
                </td>
                <td>        
                    @Ajax.ActionLink("Followup", "FollowupUpdate", new { RMAKey = item.RMAKey,  FollowupDate=item.FollowupDate }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "modal", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, HttpMethod = "GET", OnSuccess = "onModalLoad" }, new { @class = "icon-secondary note" })
                </td>

            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The above code i am using   @Html.EditorFor(model => model.First().FollowupDate). This is my problem occur here i get the date and send the date to partial view. How to generate the date dinamically?

Comment: Is `FollowupDate` a property of your model? Why are you always returning the value of the first item in your collection?

Comment: What do you mean by dynamically, if you'd like to generate one on the fly, set the value in the model itself before rendering the view. Else, bind the value in the controller during save.

Comment: Actually i don't know exactly.. i used **@Html.EditorFor(model => model.First().FollowupDate),it's wrong**. Exactly I want to select the date in datatable. Then the date will be move to next page partial view.